# Trying to filter a Grouped GridLayout Listview by clicking a button

Tags: listview, windows-8, filter, winjs

I am learning WinJs but having issues with my app.
I have a Grouped ListView that I display in a Gridlayout.
I use a template and in the header of the template, there are three buttons.  In my Javascript, I have a function that filters the list by criticality then group it.  When I click the button, I pass the criticality, then use it in the filter.  The issue I am having is that the function that does the filtering and grouping gets called when the buttons are clicked but the display doesn't change.

I have searched the site and found a few topics that I thought may help but they were all for Android apps.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

code snippet:

[data.js]

```
(function () {
  "use strict";

  var groupedItemsList;
  var jobStatusCriticality = "";
  var groupedJobs, filteredDataList;

  var dataList = new WinJS.Binding.List();

  function listData() { //removed for web}

  WinJS.Namespace.define("JobGroup.Functions", {
    setupJobGroup: function setupGroup(jsc) {
        if (jsc != "") {
          filteredDataList = dataList.createFiltered(
                function (dataItem) {
                    if (dataItem.jobCriticality == jsc) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
          );
          filteredDataList.notifyReload();
        }
        else {
            filteredDataList = dataList;
        }

        groupedJobs = filteredDataList.createGrouped(
            function (dataItem) {
                return dataItem.jobStatus;
            },
            function (dataItem) {
                return { status: dataItem.jobStatus };
            },
            function (first, second) {
                return first.charCodeAt(0) - second.charCodeAt(0);
            }
        );
    }
});

JobGroup.Functions.setupJobGroup(jobStatusCriticality);
WinJS.Namespace.define("DataExample", { myList: groupedJobs });
WinJS.UI.processAll().then(listData);
```

[default.html]

```
<div id="mediumListIconTextTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
  //remove for web
</div>

<div id="headerTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
  <div id="sortType"> 
    <div id="sortAll"><span><button id="viewAllBtn" type="button" onclick="JobGroup.Functions.setupJobGroup('')">View All</button></span></div>
    <div id="sortCritical"><span><button id="viewCriticalBtn" type="button" onclick="JobGroup.Functions.setupJobGroup('CRITICAL')">Critical</button></span></div>
    <div id="sortWarning"><span><button id="viewWarningBtn" type="button" onclick="JobGroup.Functions.setupJobGroup('WARNING')">Warning</button></span></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="groupedListView"
  data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" 
  data-win-options="{itemDataSource: DataExample.myList.dataSource, 
    itemTemplate: select('#mediumListIconTextTemplate'),
    groupDataSource: DataExample.myList.groups.dataSource,
    groupHeaderTemplate: select('#headerTemplate'),
    layout: {type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout}}">
</div>
```

[default.js]
    //contains the standard default code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick scan so you may have to play with this a bit but I think this is in the ballpark...

You need to update the **ListView** with the new **dataSource**.  The way you have things wired now, you bind the **List** to **myList.dataSource** which is actually the **groupedJobs**.  When you click a button, you create a new data sort but **createGrouped** creates an entirely new object so there is no notification to the **ListView** that something has changed - the **ListView** is still bound to the old object.  Calling

```
groupedListView.winControl.itemDataSource = groupedJobs.dataSource;
groupedListView.winControl.groupDataSource = groudedJobs.groups.dataSource;
```

at the end of your **listData** function would do the trick I think.